# How to Extract, Change and Replace Data?

Tags: excel, vba, replace, macros, data-retrieval

Maybe I have used the wrong phrase to search but I have not been able to find a solution to the following challenge for Excel/VBA:

In Sheet 1 I have a database of order data from cells A1 to F10. Each row contains data for one order. Column A contains the order number.

As first step I, in sheet 2, wish to make a search on the order number and retrieve all data for that order into cells A5 to F5 in sheet 2.

After reviewing the data (and running another macro to recalculate the sales price) I wish to have the revised data replace the original data in sheet 1.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: show use sample dataset and expected results.

Comment: Sorry, I cant even figure out how to copy/paste example dataset in here :-(

Answer (score 0):

The 1st part does not need macro.
vlookup (fkeres magyarul) is your function. If you put this function in A5-F5 fields in sheet 2, looking for a given order number, in Sheet1 $A$1:$F$10, entering the required column number, asking exact match (FALSE), it works nicely. I entered the functions parameters in my previous sentence.

The 2nd part needs macro which makes Copy Paste back.

OR

Look for the requested order row in sheet2 A5 cell with MATCH (HOL.VAN magyarul) function, like =MATCH(A1;Sheet1!A1:A10;0)
and put INDIRECT (INDIREKT magyarul) function, like =INDIRECT("Sheet1!B"&A5;TRUE) in B5, etc.

In this case the Copy-Paste back macro is (starting from Sheet2):

```
Myorder = Range("A5").Value
Range("B5:F5").Select ' A5 is the row number of order, not the order No
Selection.Copy
Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("Munka1").Range("A" & Myorder)
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

...or very similar

Comment: I must misunderstand something. If I run the above macro then the data is pasted into the row equal the order number. E.g. if sheet 1 has order number 87654 in row 7 then when I run the revised data is inserted in row 87654. 

Further, I cannot get the 'match' order to work. The system do not accept the first ';'!?